# Specify a Scala singleton as a <servlet-class> in web.xml

Tags: scala, google-app-engine, servlets, singleton, jetty

I am trying to use my singleton object to implement a servlet for Google App Engine (which seems to be using Jetty 6.1 under the hood). This is contained in my web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-class>my.namespace.Download$.MODULE$</servlet-class>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/download.fit</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Download is simply:

```
object Download extends HttpServlet
```

However when starting a server, I get following exception:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.namespace.Download$.MODULE$`

When I use a plain class instead, everything works fine:

```
<servlet-class>my.namespace.Download</servlet-class>
```

and

```
object Download extends HttpServlet
```

Is there anything special needed to use Scala singleton object as a servlet?